# React-bootstrap carousel buttons customizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, carousel, bootstrap-5

What's the problem. I have a carousel and buttons that must not be inside the carousel. How can I connect them with the carousel? On the React-Bootstrap website, they suggest using the activeIndex, but in this case, the carousel isn't cyclic like with the standard buttons. After the last image, the button just sends you back to the beginning instead of showing the first image after the last one. I could also just paste components into the prevIcon and nextIcon, but then the buttons are inside the carousel, not outside.

here is my component

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label */
import '../../styles/Banner/Banner.scss';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

import { useState } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Button } from '../Button';

export const Banner: React.FC = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSlideLeft = () => {
    if (index === 0) {
      setIndex(2);
    } else {
      setIndex(index - 1);
    }
  };

  const handleSlideRight = () => {
    if (index === 2) {
      setIndex(0);
    } else {
      setIndex(index + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="banner">
      <div className="banner__carousel-container">
        <Button
          content="arrow"
          arrowDirection="left"
          onClick={handleSlideLeft}
        />

        <Carousel
          controls={false}
          indicators={false}
          activeIndex={index}
        >
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              src={example.png}
              alt="phones"
              className="banner__image"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              src={example.png}
              alt="tablets"
              className="banner__image"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              src={example.png}
              alt="accessories"
              className="banner__image"
            />
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>

        <Button
          content="arrow"
          arrowDirection="right"
          onClick={handleSlideRight}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="banner__badges">
        <button
          type="button"
          className={classNames('banner__badge', {
            active: index === 0,
          })}
          onClick={() => setIndex(0)}
        />

        <button
          type="button"
          className={classNames('banner__badge', {
            active: index === 1,
          })}
          onClick={() => setIndex(1)}
        />

        <button
          type="button"
          className={classNames('banner__badge', {
            active: index === 2,
          })}
          onClick={() => setIndex(2)}
        />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

that's the screen where I show what i mean about inside and outside buttons
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv2LN.jpg

Comment: It would be better if you could create a reproducible sample and add the link, maybe you could use codesandbox, stackblitz to create one ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying it manually , what you can do is using React useRef to trigger corousal next,prev in your custom buttons.

```js
 const corousalRef = useRef(null);
 const handleSlideLeft = () => {
    corousalRef.current.prev();
  };
  const handleSlideRight = () => {
    corousalRef.current.next();
  };
  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };
  ...
  <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        controls={false}
        indicators={false}
        ref={corousalRef}
   >
  ...
```

Comment: OMG.  I've seen it somewhere, but I don't remember where and there is nothing about it on the official page. You are my savior!